# Warning GDB Inappropriate IOCTL for device

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, qt-creator, stdout

I'm using a program that crashes on Linux (and works fine on Windows) and I don't know why.
I've got quite a strange error, which is : `&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Inappropriate ioctl for devide\n"` when I launch the debugger.

Informations I found on the internet made me think it has something to do with an output.

The concerned file crashes at `lign 0` and contains only this function :

```
void Sync_Print::stdOutFormat (const char* format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    Locker Protect (Synchro);
    ::vprintf(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

`Sync_Print` is the name for my class that implements `static void stdOutFormat(const char* format, ...);` and `static Mutex Synchro;`

In my debugger on QtCreator, it says that the program crashed in the file named `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` on lign 0. The program crashes immediately, I can't even output anything using `std` ... Even with an empty main and no include it crashes.

I'm kinda lost here ... I don't know if it would be accurate to give more code. If you need any precisions I'd be glad to give them ...

I'm under Linux Ubuntu 12.04, with QtCreator and GCC 4.7.2. I'm using Qt 4.

Comment: Sounds like your program is crashing when initialising a static object. Set a break point in the constructor for every static object and global variable you have.

Comment: Well I did that in my `Sync_Print` file. In fact it can't even reach the debug point. I've got a message that says `The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system. Signal Name : SIGABRT Signal Meaning : Aborted` ... So I don't even know if it can reach the debug points ... Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that the error message you get is from GDB itself, which is trying to control your terminal in a way that isn't compatible with your system. Can you try starting `gdb` with some other program, e.g. `gdb vi` or `gdb sh`?

Comment: I typed `gdb sh` and `gdb vi`, it starts GNU gdb and says it is configured as `i686-linux-gnu`, reads symbols from `/usr/bin/vi` or `/bin/sh` and gives me a command ligne like `(gdb)`. Is that useful ?